# React Native - VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation

Tags: react-native, expo, scrollview

I'm working on an app for existing web application with expo cli.

I have completed the home screen but I'm getting this warning when using `ScrollView`

> VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with
> the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container
> instead.

I have a folder `screens` where I've all the pages of the website. so currently I have `Home.js` where I have different sections.

```
<View>
  <Showcase />
  <StepsList />
  <HomeInfo />
  <HomeCorporateMenu />
  <HomeMonthlyMenus />
</View>
```

Then rendeing this component in the root component `App.js`. but I was not able to scroll down to see other sections.

So I've added `SafeAreaView` and `ScrollView` components. now I'm able to scroll but sometimes I get that warning in the console.

I have looked it up SO and found some solutions.

Added `style={{ flex: 1 }}` and `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` to `ScrollView` component

But Still getting the same warning. Any suggestions?

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView>
    <Header />
    <HomeScreen />
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The warning is, obviously, telling you that you shouldn't nest multiple [VirtualizedList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist) (FlatList and SectionList) components with the same orientation (the orientation of your lists is probably `vertical`).

To do it properly, and for the warning to disappear, you have to use the [`ListHeaderComponent`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#listheadercomponent) or [`ListFooterComponent`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#listfootercomponent) prop of the `VirtualizedList` and nest them like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const ListFooterComponent = (
    <>
      <FlatList
        // other FlatList props
        data={stepsListData}
      />
      <FlatList
        // other FlatList props
        data={homeInfoData}
      />
      <FlatList
        // other FlatList props
        data={homeCorporateMenuData}
      />
      {/* ... */}
    </>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      // other FlatList props
      data={showcaseData}
      ListFooterComponent={ListFooterComponent}
    />
  );
};
```

Or another possible **workaround** (and not an official resolution) would be to use a `FlatList` with empty `data` and `renderItem` props instead of using a `ScrollView`. Instead of this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Header />
        <HomeScreen />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

You can use this:

```
const emptyData = [];

const renderNullItem = () => null;

const App = () => {
  const ListFooterComponent = (
    <>
      <Header />
      <HomeScreen />
    </>
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={emptyData}
        renderItem={renderNullItem}
        ListFooterComponent={ListFooterComponent}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```