# Is there a FlatList-like View without the scrolling?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Basically, I have a list of items (with images) inside a single `Card` (custom component). Because the rendering of those items is slow, I wanted to use a `FlatList` to render them incrementally.

Unfortunately, I get the expected error

```
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews ...
```

But I don't *actually* want to use a `ScrollView` inside the `Card`. I just want to render a few Items in a single `Card`, which should change its size to fit all the items.

- Setting `scrollEnabled={false}` on the `FlatList` still shows the error above.
- Using the `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent` props is not an option, because the content above and below should NOT be rendered inside the `Card`.

Here is a minimal example of what I mean:

```js
const Comp = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
      <Text>Header</Text>

      <Card>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Image source={{uri: item.localImageUrl}}/>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          initialNumToRender={0}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior='automatic'
        />
      </Card>

      <Text>Footer</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

What's interesting though, that aside from the error - I get the result I expected, and I could *technically* hide that error and ignore it, but that does not seem like the recommended approach.

### Important: I am not *specifically* looking for a `FlatList` solution. It could technically be any Component that renders items incrementally in a non-blocking way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939975/react-native-virtualizedlists-should-never-be-nested-inside-plain-scrollviews)

Comment: @Kapobajza No, unfortunately not. The answer you linked uses the `ListHeaderComponent` & `ListFooterComponent` props, which are not viable in my case, for reasons already stated in my question.

Comment: And why should they not be rendered inside the `Card`? I would suggest changing your `Card` component and the overall structure of the `Comp` component. Otherwise you would have to go against RN's practices and find a hacky workaround (if there is one).

Comment: @Kapobajza Why should it be rendered inside the card, when it is content I want to show **outside** the card? I mean it's a design choice, that should not be open for debate. If you have a suggestion on how you would change it, I am open to hearing it. I think this is a common use-case, and I highly doubt there is anything speaking against wanting a layout like described.

Answer (score 0):

The important point with a Flatlist is the reusing of cells so that not all components need to be rendered at the same time. So scrolling is an important part of this. On the other hand two scrollable components inside eachother will make it impossible for the system to know which component should be scrolled.

If there are only 3 items and it should not be scrollable you can just include a list of items inside the Scrollview like this:

```
const Comp = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
      <Text>Header</Text>

      <Card>
        { data.map((item, index) => {
           return (
             <Text key={index}>{item.title}</Text>
           );
        }) }
      </Card>

      <Text>Footer</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is what I am doing, but as stated in the question this does have performance problems, as I am rendering about 30 images. Therefore, I would like to render them incrementally, similar to a FlatList.

Comment: I think I am irritated, you write that you want to render only a few items inside the card and show code with a <Text> element, on the other hand you mention you have items with images. If the image loading is blocking you should show the code loading the image, for the image component it makes a difference from where it is loaded for example (assets, bundle, url)

Comment: Okay, sorry, that's on me. The example should just give a basic understanding of the structure (with the `Card` and stuff), not the actual content. I will edit that to make it more clear. The image is a simple local image loaded by URL.

Comment: I think I would try to define the size of the image in advance and then let the image load, on the other hand you could try the Image.onLoadEnd to load one by one adding the next item to the state once the previous has finished, but as mentioned this is a different question that you might want to post seperately to find users experienced with this subject.

Comment: How is this a different question? I want a component that acts like `FlatList` does, without the scrolling capabilities. Exactly as stated in the question. I have even written a big notice on the end to make it extra clear. If there does not exist such a solution, I can create my own solution, but I absolutely expect that something like this already exists - hence the question.